# Confirm if a customer's credit card is active and in good standing using the Paypal API

Tags: php, paypal

Using the Paypal API, how would I confirm if a customer's credit card is active and in good standing?

Comment: Which API are you using?  PayFlow, DoDirectPayment, REST DCC, Braintree..??

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure what the actual name of the API is called but he URL for it is https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

Comment: Are you working with basic HTML form buttons or are you working with actual API web services?

Comment: @Andrew I use the HTML form buttons (either those provided by PayPal or my own) to access the actual API web services.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Do you mean you're posting your HTML forms to PHP scripts that are then generating API calls to PayPal?  If so then you'd be able to tell me which API you're using.

Comment: @Andrew No, I use the the HTML form to make to the calls to the API and the API returns a JSON response to my script.

Comment: Then how are you processing the result?  And why did you include the PHP tag in your question?  Can you post your form code?

Comment: @Andrewl The API returns a JSON response to my processing script where it is stored in a database and an email message is sent to me indicating whether payment was accepted  or declined.

Comment: @Andrew I can post code snipets of the parameters sent to the API and snipets of the processing script if you would like.